# What Qt GUI Containers to use? Also Related Video Display issue - Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt5

I am trying to design an application to play multiple video (media) files and allow user modification capability on each one (eg, scaling, rotating, inverting etc of videos). I started by studying `Phonon`, but after going into it for a while read that it is no longer supported (or its support is doubtful) in >= `Qt5`. So then i went back and now i'm looking at qtmultimedia - `QMediaPlayer`. Though I have come from c#-WPF background i have done some earlier work on Qt-C++. But this time I'm stuck and confused on what widgets i must use. `QMediaPlayer` can show its output (video) on `QVideoWidget`, `QGraphicsVideoItem` and `QAbstractVideoSurface`. Since I need the capabilities of rotation etc, i believe i must incorporate QGraphicsScene/View.

<1> So what should the approach be? I did this: used `QVideoWidget` -> added this to `QGraphicsProxyWidget` via its `setWidget`() (though `setWidget`() takes `QWidget`* and `QVideoWidget` is not derived from `QWidget` as i see in Qt Assistant -- why is this allowed btw?) -> Added this `QGraphicProxyWidget` to `QGraphicsScene` via `addItem`() -> added this `QGraphicsScene` to `QGraphicsView` while constructing it -> added `QGraphicsView` to `QMainWindow` via `setCentralWidget`(). Is this fine? When to use `QGraphicsVideoItem` and `QAbstractVideoSurface`?

<2> When adding multiple `QVideoWidget` in the following manner i don't see any video or the `QVideoWidget` itself (i've painted to distinguish it). What am i doing wrong? (there is audio output though):

```
    QVideoWidget *pVideoWidget1 = new QVideoWidget(0);
    pVideoWidget1->setPalette(QPalette(QColor(255,0,0),QColor(0,255,0)));
    QVideoWidget *pVideoWidget2 = new QVideoWidget(0);
    pVideoWidget2->setPalette(QPalette(QColor(255,0,0),QColor(0,0,255)));

    m_pMediaPlayer1 = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    m_pMediaPlayer2 = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    m_pMediaPlayer1->setVideoOutput(pVideoWidget1);
    m_pMediaPlayer2->setVideoOutput(pVideoWidget2);

    m_pCustomGraphicsProxy1 = new CustomGraphicsProxy(0); //this is just a class derived from QGraphicsProxyWidget to implement drag and drop of videos
    m_pCustomGraphicsProxy2 = new CustomGraphicsProxy(0);
    m_pCustomGraphicsProxy1->setWidget(pVideoWidget1);
    m_pCustomGraphicsProxy2->setWidget(pVideoWidget2);

    QGraphicsScene *pGraphicsScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QGraphicsLinearLayout *pGraphicsLinearLayout = new QGraphicsLinearLayout;

    CustomGraphicsProxy* button = new CustomGraphicsProxy(0);
    button->setWidget(new QPushButton); //this i can see
    CustomGraphicsProxy* button1 = new CustomGraphicsProxy(0);
    button1->setWidget(new QPushButton); //this i can see too

    pGraphicsLinearLayout->addItem(button);
    pGraphicsLinearLayout->addItem(m_pCustomGraphicsProxy1); //can't see
    pGraphicsLinearLayout->addItem(m_pCustomGraphicsProxy2); //can't see
    pGraphicsLinearLayout->addItem(button1);


    CustomGraphicsProxy *temp = new CustomGraphicsProxy(0);
    temp->setLayout(pGraphicsLinearLayout);
    pGraphicsScene->addItem(temp);
    temp->show();

    m_pGraphicsView = new QGraphicsView(pGraphicsScene, this);

    setCentralWidget(m_pGraphicsView);

    QObject::connect(m_pCustomGraphicsProxy1, SIGNAL(sigNewFileDragDropped()), this, SLOT(sloPlayOnWindow1()));
    QObject::connect(m_pCustomGraphicsProxy2, SIGNAL(sigNewFileDragDropped()), this, SLOT(sloPlayOnWindow2()));

    //just for testing - this gives only audio no video can be seen
    m_pMediaPlayer1->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("d:/z.avi"));
    m_pMediaPlayer1->play();
```

<3> Before i study this further, am i choosing the right tools in Qt to manipulate videos as i mentioned before or something else needs to be done?

Comment: If I was you I would consider OpenCV over QT for this. Nothing to do with your specific problem but it's a suggestion since QT doesn't really shine in this kind of applications and it's not meant to be used for this kind of applications.

Comment: @user1824407 : ok. i just found a youtube video on OpenCV + Qt [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ONxIy8itRA) while i go through it could you pls provide me with a solution of the problem above?

Comment: if you want to use OpenCV open another question otherwise Opencv will be OT here, i suggest to delete this question and open a new one if you want to change the framework and the topic for your question. By the way OpenCV is really popular in its field and you can find many tutorial on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're building your own custom widget for the player. In that case use QWidget in designer and promote it. That will work. Here's the link for [How To?](http://www.tinesoft.com/qt/use-custom-widgets-with-qt-designer-promotion-technique)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.